# Data is not getting insterted into database, but not getting any exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I am working on ejb + JPA (Hibernate) application. When I insert the data into database, its not getting inserted. But no error is thrown from sessionbean.

Below is code.

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void insterCustomerDetails(Customer customer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            System.out.println("properties:::"+em.getProperties());
            System.out.println("Model :::"+em.getMetamodel());
        System.out.println("Name ::::" + customer.getName() + "::customer id ::"+customer.getCustomer_id()+"::email::"+customer.getEmail_id()+"::address::"+customer.getAddress()+
                ":::ph number::"+customer.getPhNumber());
        em.persist(customer);
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

**Beanclasse**

```
package retail.model.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5256938732963606407L;
    private int customer_id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email_id;
    private int phNumber;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "addres")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "email_add")
    public String getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public void setEmail_id(String email_id) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "ph_number")
    public int getPhNumber() {
        return phNumber;
    }

    public void setPhNumber(int phNumber) {
        this.phNumber = phNumber;
    }

     public String validate(){
          if(name!=null && name!=""){
          System.out.println("chandan");
          return "viewCustomerDetails";
          }
          else{
          return "viewCustomerDetails";
          }
          }
}
```

**ManagedBean**

```
public String createCustomer() throws NamingException{
    try{
    System.out.println("in Create customer method +++++++++++++++++++++++");
    Properties p = new Properties();
    //p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
    p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
    p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700"); //any configured port different from 3700 - 34513
    InitialContext c = new InitialContext(p);
    System.out.println("in Create customer method remote+++++++++++++++++++++++");
    CustomerSessionBeanRemote remote = (CustomerSessionBeanRemote) c.lookup("java:global/RetailProducts/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote");
                                                                            //java:global/RetailService/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote
     //java:global/RetailProducts/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote
    System.out.println("in Create customer method remote222+++++++++++++++++++++++");
    remote.insterCustomerDetails(getCustomer());
    remote.showCustDetails();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.exit(1);
    return "viewCustomerDetails";
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="RetailUnit" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!-- the JNDI data source-->
        <jta-data-source>java/customer</jta-data-source>
        <properties> 
            <!-- if this is true, hibernate will print (to stdout) the SQL it executes, 
                so you can check it to ensure it's not doing anything crazy
                 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
                 <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/company;create=true" />
              <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
              <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="123" /> -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <!-- since most database servers have slightly different versions of the 
                SQL, Hibernate needs you to choose a dialect so it knows the subtleties of 
                talking to that server -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <!-- this tell Hibernate to update the DDL when it starts, very useful 
                for development, dangerous in production -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is the console output:

```
INFO: Name ::::sdasdas::customer id ::0::email::sdasdasd::address::asdasdasd:::ph number::2323234
INFO: Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        CUSTOMER
        (customer_id, addres, email_add, Name, ph_number) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
INFO: Hibernate: 

values
    identity_val_local()
```

I checked the database whether it is inserting or not using commandline of derby database tool. There are no rows in customer table.

### Update

Now getting exception:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:985)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getTransaction(EntityManagerWrapper.java:857)
    at retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanImpl.insterCustomerDetails(CustomerSessionBeanImpl.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at $Proxy255.insterCustomerDetails(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at retail.ejb.service.__CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.insterCustomerDetails(retail/ejb/service/__CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at retail.ejb.service._CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Wrapper.insterCustomerDetails(retail/ejb/service/_CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at retail.web.mbean.CustomerMB.createCustomer(CustomerMB.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Are you acquiring the transaction object programatically in your bean ? Can you please post the full bean code ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using container managed persistence, so you can't forcefully end a transaction.

What you do want to do it execute `em.flush()`.  You will also need to annotate your EJB method with it's transactionality.  So put a `@Requires` on it.

Comment: What line is he forcefully ending the transaction ?

Comment: You mean @required ? It is assumed by default if not used.

Comment: Maybe forcefully ending the transaction is the wrong term.  You can't control the transaction when using CMP.

Comment: He may be acquiring transaction object in his code programmatically. I have asked him for full bean code. lets see !